# Bitbucket API Access token expiry

Tags: token, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am making an app which integrates with bitbucket using oauth.
My question is how do I get the token details such as the *token expiry date* or the *token permissions*.
Is there any endpoint on the bitbucket API which will give me these details

**SOLVED:** Bitbucket Tokens have an expiry time of 1 hour after which we need to use the provided refresh token to refresh our access token.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket don't have a published method to query an access token.

You can see all the OAUTH methods here:

[OAuth on Bitbucket Cloud](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html)

It probably doesn't matter, since they expire tokens every 60 minutes, so you would most likely need to request a refresh any way. And in the refresh it will give you a new access token, and tell you the expiry again (in 60 minutes) and also the permissions (scopes) you were asking about.

A refresh response doesn't need to occur within the 60 minute limit, so you just refresh when you are about to use it. It will respond with:

{"access_token": "", "scopes": "", "expires_in": 3600, "refresh_token": "", "token_type": "bearer"}

Where permissions would be like: "wiki pullrequest project team account" and they are also listed under the linked page above (in the Scopes section).